# how to show detailed gcc version number?

Tags: gcc, mingw, versioning

I know `g++ --version` but it only shows very simple version number with no build id or build date. How to get more detailed information ?

for example here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/ are 9 versions and they show the same info when asked in this way.

Comment: i think you are confusing the development builds and the releases.

Comment: You can get more information with `g++ -v --version`. I don't know if it'll have the information you want (but I know it'll have information that you don't want).